# CKAN: Disabling Logging INFO message datastore_search action render time

Tags: logging, ckan

When I access a resource page, I see something like this in my web server error log file:

```
[Mon Feb 29 10:15:24.835165 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 18349:tid 2016-02-29 10:15:24,834 INFO [ckan.lib.base] /api/3/action/datastore_search render time 0.021 seconds
```

Do you know if there is a way to disable logging of that message (that in fact isn't an error).

I'm using CKAN 2.4.1.

Comment: Please do apply patches to your CKAN version - 2.4.1 is not recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the log level in your CKAN config (default is `/etc/ckan/default/production.ini`)

```
[logger_ckan]
level = INFO
...
[logger_ckanext]
level = DEBUG
```

Valid levels are INFO, DEBUG, WARNING and ERROR. So if you don't want to see DEBUG and INFO, set the levels to WARNING, and restart ckan (apache).

These messages all get mislabelled as an "error" by virtue of being in the server's 'error' log file. The reason why they are directed there is because it's convenient to send all logging to stderr and let the web server (apache) store it. It saves the app the problem of multiple threads/processes trying to append to the same file and possibly rotate the log file too. I think officially (apache at least) the error file is for both errors and "diagnostic information", it is all labelled as "error", which is somewhat confusing.

I'd be pleased to hear other suggestions of how we configure CKAN to log - if there is a better way we can change the default configuration.